# Google My Business(GMB) v4.9 Account API's sunset/deprecation on 2021-05-23?

Tags: api, google-api, deprecated, google-my-business-api

With the new Google My Business version 4.9, the Account related API's were migrated to the new AccountManagement API's
Ref: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates
Sunset Date: 2021-05-23

Does this mean the account-related APIs will no longer work after the specified date for Both v4.9 and older versions?